# Use identityServer4 4.1.1 in VB .NET 4.7.2 Project

Tags: vb.net, identityserver4

We have an older Visual Basic application using .NET 4.7.2.  We also have an SSO project built using .NET Core 2.2.  Currently both projects use IdentityServer4 version 2.5.3.  I am now updating the SSO project to .NET Core 3.1 and IdentityServer4 to version 4.1.1.

However, when I try to use the same version of IdentityServer4 in the VB project, it gives the error:

`Could not install package 'IdentityServer4 4.1.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Can I leave IS4 version 2.5.3 in the VB project while targeting IS4 version 4.1.1 in the SSO project?  Will IS4 continue to work with different versions? Is there a way to target IS4 version 4.1.1 in a .NET 4.7.2 project?

Comment: You didn't explain why need two identityserver instances close together. If those are two separate identity providers, there is no requirement to run the same version of the software. They are both oidc-certified.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the IdentityServer4 Nuget package for version 4.1.1, then it says it depends on .NET Core 3.1. So unfortunately, you can't install it on .NET Framework 4.x

See https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4/4.1.1

In general I think you should install IdentityServer4 as its own service and perhaps then its easier for you to upgrade to .NET Core or .NET 5/6?.